# Connect to AWS RDS MySQL from RStudio

Tags: mysql, r, amazon-web-services

I have created an aws account and need to create a connection from RStudio to the aws database in order to write data and read in subsets of the data.

I tried the example here https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-dplyr.html and it works fine. However, when trying to connect to my own instance I receive the following error:

> Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
>     Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'Administrator'@'cpc75655-alde5-2-0-cust376.6-2.cable.virginm.net' (using password: YES) .

I have created and assigned my instance to a Security group with Administrator access. What should I try to fix this?
I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Greg, what type of database? Your error means that the username and password that you are using is not correct for the database server. Also note the username in the failed message.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I am trying to connect to a MySQL database (RDS). The username ('Administrator') and the password I am using work to log me into the aws console so they do seem to be correct.

Comment: The username for the Amazon Management Console is not the same as the RDS username. When you created the RDS instance, you specified the username and password. You need to use the username that you specified for RDS.

Comment: Thanks @John I seem to have some progress, I will check and then mark as complete